# Downloaded videos are not playing properly on Video and VLC

Tags: video, vlc, youtube

Recently I began having a problem playing downloaded videos on both Videos and VLC media player. The videos were downloaded with youtube-dl and previously I was able to play them. I don't have this problem with all videos I downloaded with youtube-dl, just some of them.

The problem is that the image and sound freeze for a long time, jump to another frame a few seconds into the video, play normally for a few seconds, then freeze again etc. It's as if my PC is unable to play them.

I am able to view these same videos with no problems online, on YouTube, at the sources I downloaded them from. Here is a link to one of the videos I did have the problem playing on Videos and VLC after downloading:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fMFa7BFLyE8

Ubuntu version 20.04.2 LTS; VLC version 3.0.9.2

(I don't know which version of Videos I have. The --version command doesn't work for this program.)

Comment: Did you install ubuntu-restricted-extras?

Comment: 24601 I installed those just now and the problem still exists. However, I'm not sure that they completed installation, since the user agreement window/box doesn't allow any means for the user to "accept", so I just closed the window.

Comment: 26601 - I just attempted to install the restricted extras again and got the message: "E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem." I have no idea what that means.